# Memory section handling error

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, gnu

I'm getting a link time error:

```
WARNING: /home/gulevich/development/camac-fedorov/camac/linux/k0607-lsi6/camac-k0607-lsi6.o (.ctors): unexpected non-allocatable section.
Did you forget to use "ax"/"aw" in a .S file?
Note that for example <linux/init.h> contains
section definitions for use in .S files.
```

The code causing the error (assembly in C source):

```
# if   defined(__ELF__)
#  define __SECTION_FLAGS ", \"aw\" , @progbits"
 /* writable flag needed for ld ".[cd]tors" sections bug workaround) */
# elif defined(__COFF__)
#  define __SECTION_FLAGS ", \"dr\""
 /* untested, may be writable flag needed */
# endif


asm
(
 ".section .ctors" __SECTION_FLAGS "\n"
 ".globl __ctors_begin__\n"
 "__ctors_begin__:\n"
 ".previous\n"
);
```

Is there any way to fix this? The idea is to put a varaible `__ctors_begin__` at the beginning of a certain memory section. This code is a legacy that worked fine using a different build system and older compiler.

Meaning of this assembly code explained in [an answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643264/getting-memory-section-information).

Comment: What C compiler are you using?

Comment: As an added note, the exact code you posted compiles fine in GCC 4.4.1 on 64-bit ubuntu

Comment: This is link time error, not a compile time one.
Here is version information:
linker: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.20.1-system.20100303;
compiler: gcc (Debian 4.4.2-9) 4.4.3 20100108 (prerelease).

Answer (score 1):

very long shot but is the section .ctors is defined like you want in the linker script? ld iirc has a verbose option to show the linker script.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot: 
Perhaps your linker is expecting ELF format (instead of COFF), and for some reason `__ELF__` is not defined? Have you checked the preprocessor output for this particular build?

Answer (score 0):

I would dobule check the value of `__SECTION_FLAGS` just to be sure that it indeed contains ax or aw.  I'd also be sure that `__COFF__` is not defined and that `__ELF__` is.  Failing that, it might be time to grab (is possible) a previous or future version of the compiler/linker and see if that fixes your problem.  Perhaps you could compile your code as C++ and somehow let the compiler/linker/link scritps do what they are supposed to do?  Dunno completely, but this is where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

Sections work fine. So I'll ignore this warning.